# Is breaking copyright laws allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, hadith, sunnah

Are Muslims allowed to break copyright? I mean using a software, watching a movie, listening a music or reading an e-book - that are supposed to be paid - without purchasing them.

Does it depend to the laws of the country a Muslim is living?

*Answers containing the views of different scholars/schools are more than welcome.*

Comment: See also: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/600/is-using-pirated-software-allowed - which seems to basically say "no, that is not ok"

Comment: When it comes to matters of learning and gaining knowledge scholars have different opinions, as hiding knowledge is considered a sin. Some would consider the later and say it is allowed if it is done to gain knowledge, others would say if there's any clear sign or quote that there's a copyright one should accept that and refrain from copying nevertheless. For other purposes the matter seems clearer unless there's a need (a trial of death or life) and this would hardly be the case for movies etc..