# Is it halal or haram to distribute a scanned copy of a copyrighted book?

Tags: halal-haram, piracy, digital-files

I got a book from school library which I wish to scan and distribute among my friends. My intention is to help my friends in my upcoming exam. Would this be considered haram or halal?

Would the same result apply to distributing an ebook (pdf) which someone else scanned/bought?

Comment: Why would it be haram?

Comment: The author has the phrase: "All right reserved. No part of this publication may be reproduced, or transmitted in any form or by any means, 
electronic or mechanic including photocopy, recording or any information storage and retrieval system , without permission in writing from the publisher or under license from the copyright Licensing Agency Limited..."

Comment: similar questions: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/breaking-copyright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muslims are required to abide by the law of the land in whatever country they may be living. If you are living in a country where copyright is protected by law and you do not respect the law then you are performing a haram act.

Comment: I have checked the law and it is allowed for examination and instruction purposes.

Comment: In that case there is no problem, as long as you do not try to sell it.

Comment: uh, yeah, @aasheq, you pointed it out nicely. Actually "Muslims are required to abide by the law of the land in whatever country they may be living" (if is not haram...) / So, your answer can be deserved +1 in spite of being brief answer. Good luck mate.