# Earning from a blog that provides cracked softwares for download?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software, piracy

I have a software blog where I write reviews about software and provide free download link(s). I am using AdSense in that blog for my earnings. I want to know that if I upload or share cracked software link(s) for download, e.g Sharing Adobe Photshop/Illustrator cracked version for free download, is my earnings from this blog Halal or Haram?

PS: My question is not a duplicate of 'Using Pirate Software' because I am asking about earning from the blog which provides cracked software link(s) for download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using pirated software allowed?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/600/is-using-pirated-software-allowed)

Comment: I think earning from sharing cracked software is a bit like getting money from sharing stolen properties. If using stolen properties is not lawful, sharing them should not be considered lawful, let alone earning money by sharing them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The act of sharing download files or download links of cracked software (which are not freely available) on your website, and the act of earning money off it, in my opinion, are haram, unless you have the permission (to share their software via download files or help share via download links) of the companies/publishers who develop and sell those software.

Quran verse **5:38** prohibits stealing clearly. Obtaining a software product illegally without paying the price its owner asks for it, or sharing its files, or sharing download links to it can also be considered as a type of stealing, because it is an act that is against the will of its developer/publisher.

Imagine that you are running a software company, developing and selling useful software for people. If you and hundreds of your staff spent millions of money, thousands of development hours in developing a software, and then put the finished product for sale, so that you and your staff can provide for their families, would you like your software to be cracked and shared freely?

Please don't do it. Devil continuously keeps whispering to do haram things that will bring easy money. We shall resist that.