# Am I allowed to pirate a game I bought before on another platform?

Tags: halal-haram, software, piracy

I got Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas on my Android phone then it was stolen, so I bought it on Windows 10 via Windows Store but then, I decided to switch to Linux.

The reason why, if that would change anything is that I was afraid that using Windows without a license (not activated but, not cracked) is considered stealing.

May I torrent the game? The Steam version which is the one available on torrent sites is older but, is more expensive than the Windows Store version.

This question differs from [Is using pirated software allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/600/17163) in that I'm asking about if using pirated software is allowed in a situation where I bought it before on another platform.

Comment: I was asking about if using pirated software is allowed but, with an extra condition, that I bought it before.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE; when responding to feedback, it's best to [edit] the question to make it self contained (comments are regarded as [ephemeral](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/479/17163) and [temporary "Post-It" notes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)).  I did it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grand theft Auto is a game which falls under prohibited category. Game is built on ideas of crime like killing people, stealing private property, treating woman as merchandise.

Buying this game is helping developers in spreading ideas of corruption on earth.

> Quran 5:2 And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression.

Pirated software without copyright can be used on other platforms. With copyright if they allow to use its fine, else not permissible.

> Quran 5:1 O you who believe fullfil contracts.

Related verdict : [Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/97681)

Comment: You may think I am munafiq but, after writing this question, I thought about that, I read a comment on this website talking about not doing things for the sake of Allah's pleasure and I decided to forget about it, may be Allah just stops me from playing it, the problem now is that I can control myself but, my little brother wants to play an open game like this, What should I do about that?

Comment: Allah knows such a thought(Hippocrite) never occurred to me. Pray to Allah for your brothers guidance and advice him with best of speeches. Another alternative path, destroy this game, if it's destructible.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: *Am I allowed to pirate a game I bought before on another platform?*

Comment: Answer edited to cater question