# What is the punishment for someone who pirates digital files?

Tags: sharia, hudud, digital-files, theft

It is agreed upon that piracy is theft according to the question [What is the Islamic stance on Internet Piracy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-does-islam-stand-on-internet-piracy)

However, cutting the hand of someone for downloading a bad pop song seems a little… excessive as it would leave most of my friends without hands. Is there a law suited for those who commit very minor theft or if they commit theft but aren't prosecuted?

Comment: Are you asking about piracy specifically or minor theft in general?

Comment: @ashes999 Asking about piracy specifically. I'm assuming it uses the same ruling as minor theft as there wouldn't be any hadith for copyright infringement.

Comment: AFAIK, the cutting of the hands is a voluntary punishment, for those who have realised their mistake and want to be cleansed for that particular punishment in hell.

Comment: The same rulings of piracy applies to software like DreamWeaver, photoshop, Windows, etc.m that are sold as commercial products :)

Comment: newer but related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16670/if-someone-is-poor-can-he-she-use-pirated-softwares/16675#16675

Answer (score 1):

Hadd punishments can't be prescribed for piracy because this kind of theft is not like normal theft. There is no witness for this. The only evidence is the computer records.

The Islamic goverments will enforce tazir punishments for such issues. But the person may avert the punishment by paying blood money to the affected person or company.

Comment: reference plz??