# Is it halal to avail service from a company that makes use of pirated software?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software, piracy

My electricity provider uses pirated Windows in their desktops. Since I pay bills to them and they make use of these desktops to register my bill, will using the electricity for the purpose of work make my income through that work haram?

Comment: Please see related question : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/207/what-is-the-islamic-stance-on-internet-piracy

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, your question is that if its halal to get paid by working on piracy software? 
then According to Islam this is simply straight, If you are not paying for the software you are using then its **WRONG**
but if we talk about today's realities then we are not doing many things right.
What about getting **profit**(sood) on your money?  If you are not directly getting profit then most of the time many of us getting salaries from companies who are paying us from bank profit and many other scenarios included. Similarly many users in small countries using piracy windows while **Microsoft** off course knows that but they never sui(law case) on you because using their product you are indirectly paying them by using their different services. Everyone cant pay or afford their prices for Original software's and piracy windows also not contains the genuine window and Microsoft knows that thing well. So try to take away these things from yourself as much as you can.