# Is earning money from link shortener haram or halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

Im putting download links of APK's game on youtube, apk's in which i provide paid games for free in a download link. Whenever they press the link, i earn money. As far, like 1200 pressed and downloaded it, i got only $0.80. So i would like to know if this money is haram or halal

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what you're promoting, i.e. links to paid games, is haraam. Because, it is piracy. See this:
[What is the Islamic stance on Internet piracy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/207/what-is-the-islamic-stance-on-internet-piracy)

**This alone makes the income from promoting these stuff haraam.**

But to address your question, if the content you were promoting were permissible and the ads on the link shortener did not go against Islamic principles, then there would have been nothing wrong. But, it is highly unlikely that link shorteners don't have ads that go against Islamic principles. In fact, most of them usually contain links to inappropriate sites.

And finally, there is also the case of whether video games themselves are halaal. They may contain music, nudity, gambling etc. Plus, there is the issue of promoting wastage of time.

Answer (score 0):

See, link shorteners use ads for revenue. So it clearly depends on the advertisers policies and link shortening website. 
If the link shortening website asks users to click on its ads then your revenue is haram. 
If there are no ads on the website you use and they still pay you then its halal.
I recommend use shorte.st, they don't add any third party ads in its website