# Is piracy haram?

Tags: halal-haram, piracy

Now a days we live in a society where we use computers on daily basis.such as work places, universities etc...but in almost every computer we use pirated software...
Such as I am a student of architecture.To complete my design I have to use pirated software.And after graduation when I enter in workplace I have to work with architectural firm that also use pirated software for design.the software are very much costly and as an student we cannot afford it.
So in this case what should I do?
Will my earnings be halal if I used pirated software for designing?

Comment: Does this answer your question :
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/207/what-is-the-islamic-stance-on-internet-piracy?rq=1

Comment: You don't need to do piracy. Like if you are using Photoshop try using "gimp" Instead, it works like Photoshop but free. Just like that try finding free alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Is piracy haram?

As a general related ruling: As much as I know, haram/robbery is haram/robbery; even in cyberspace. Since a right of a person(s)/companies will be stolen, anyway.

[http://wikifeqh.ir](http://wikifeqh.ir/%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%82%D8%AA_(%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87))  (stealing (feqh))

Answer (score -1):

Stealing is a major sin in Islam. Every major sin should be avoided because it can only be forgiven by proper repentance. Piracy is similar to stealing or robbery. You must avoid this sin. May Allah show you the right path.

Comment: Though your answer is certainly correct, I would suggest you add some references to it to further strengthen your claim.