# Is it haram to pirate Windows 10?

Tags: halal-haram

Bismillah.
Is it haram to pirate Windows 10? the watermark they put is very annoying, so I want to pirate it. Is it halal or haram to pirate it?

Answer (score 0):

Pirating is taking somebody's hard work without paying the prices, which is both cheating and stealing. Both are haram. Piracy is just a newer word for stealing online work. Take a look at this question as it answers a similar topic on piracy in general: [What is the Islamic stance on Internet piracy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/207/what-is-the-islamic-stance-on-internet-piracy)

Comment: But that watermark is really annoying and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Buy the product.